# how to effectively turn rvalue reference to lvalue in perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am implementing a simple generic functor class which can store a function as well as its arguments, and thus it can be called later. The function can be a free function or member function of a class, which takes arbitrary number of arguments. So I use perfect forwording.

Here is the my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template< typename FUNC, typename...ARGS>
class GenericFunctor{

    using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<FUNC, ARGS...>;

    std::function< ReturnType() > functor;

public:

    GenericFunctor( FUNC&& func, ARGS &&... args ){
        functor = std::bind( std::forward<FUNC>(func), std::forward<ARGS>(args)... );
    }

    void run(){
        functor();
    }
};

class Person{

    int age;
    double height;

public:

    Person( int age, double height):age(age), height( height){}

    void print(){
        std::cout << age << " " << height << "\n";
    }

    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
};


int main() {

    Person p1( 32, 183.2);

    GenericFunctor f_0( &Person::getAge, &p1 );
    f_0.run();

    GenericFunctor f_1( &Person::getAge, std::ref(p1) );
    f_1.run();

    GenericFunctor f_2( &Person::getAge, std::move(p1) );
    f_2.run();
    
    GenericFunctor f_3( &Person::getAge, p1 );
    f_3.run();
}
```

I expect the above 4 test cases can work. But in the case of f_3, I got this error:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'Person&&' to lvalue of type 'Person'
```

I know what the above message means, but I have no idea how to modify my class, GenericFunctor, to make it generic enough so that all of the above 3 cases can work just as std::thread. Could I have some guidance of how to modify my GenericFunctor?

Comment: In the future, please provide the code as a [mcve]. We want to be able to quickly compile it ourselves, without adding headers and splicing together code snippets.

Comment: will do definitely.

Comment: no need to wait for future. You can still add the missing pieces to the code. Would make the question much more accessible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTAD (class template argument deduction) doesn't respect forwarding references (treats them as rvalue references, only accepting rvalues), unless you add a custom deduction guide.

Add one after your class:

```
template <typename FUNC, typename ...ARGS>
GenericFunctor(FUNC &&, ARGS &&...) -> GenericFunctor<FUNC, ARGS...>;
```

---

But the whole class doesn't really need to have `FUNC` and `ARGS...` as template parameters. Only the constructor needs them.

The whole class only needs the return type. You can write a deduction guide to avoid having to write it manually:

```
template <typename R>
class GenericFunctor
{
    std::function<R()> functor;

    // ...

    template <typename FUNC, typename ...ARGS>
    GenericFunctor(FUNC &&func, ARGS &&... args) {/*...*/}
};

template <typename FUNC, typename ...ARGS>
GenericFunctor(FUNC &&, ARGS &&...) -> GenericFunctor<std::invoke_result_t<FUNC &&, ARGS &&...>>;
```

Comment: thanks for your ans again...After you gave the hint in the previous question, I tried to move "template< typename FUNC, typename...ARGS>" to the constructor. the it can't be complied...that's why I keep it there.

Comment: @blackYellow Ah, fair enough, you need the return type. See the edit.